# Parameterised Onclick function not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to show print popup when I click on pdf link in chrome and want to open the pdf in tab for IE and FF.My code is working fine in FF AND CHROME but when I run it in IE it is showing FUNCTION printObjectPdf() is undefined. Please help.

**Here is my code**

```
 <style type="text/css">
        @media print 
        {
            .dontprint{display:none} 
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function printIframePdf(iframeId=''){
        alert(iframeId);
            window.frames[iframeId].focus();
            try {
                window.frames[iframeId].print();
            }
            catch(e){
                window.print();
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        function printObjectPdf(iframeId='') {
           try{            
                document.getElementById('idPdf').Print();
            }
            catch(e){
                if( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1 ){
                    printIframePdf(iframeId);
                }else{
                    var url = document.getElementById(iframeId).src;
                    window.open(url, '_blank');
                }
            }
        }

        function idPdf_onreadystatechange() {
            if (idPdf.readyState === 4)
                setTimeout(printObjectPdf(iframeId), 1000);
        }
    </script>
    <div class="dontprint" >
        <form><input type="button" onClick="printObjectPdf('printf1')" class="btn" value="Print"/></form>
        <form><input type="button" onClick="printObjectPdf('printf2')" class="btn" value="Print"/></form>
    </div>

    <iframe id="printf1" name="printf1" src="http://localhost/PDFtest/Device-Details.pdf" frameborder="0" width="440" height="580" style="width: 440px; height: 580px;display: none;"></iframe>

    <iframe id="printf2" name="printf2" src="http://localhost/PDFtest/Prod-Support-Material.pdf" frameborder="0" width="440" height="580" style="width: 440px; height: 580px;display: none;"></iframe>
```